# Make Entity Framework Linq query async

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a function that populates a combo box in my winform app.  The operation takes a few seconds so I'd like to make it async.

Here is the function:

```
public static List<string> GetAllPostCodeRegions(string country)
{
    using (var db = new PlaceDBContext())
    {
        var regions = db.PostCodes.Where(pc => pc.Country == country).OrderBy(pc => pc.Region).Select(pc => pc.Region).Distinct().ToList();

        return regions;
    }
}
```

I tried just adding in async keywords like below:

```
public async static Task<List<string>> GetAllPostCodeRegions(string country)
{
    using (var db = new PlaceDBContext())
    {
        var regions = db.PostCodes.Where(pc => pc.Country == country).OrderBy(pc => pc.Region).Select(pc => pc.Region).Distinct().ToList();

        return regions;
    }
}
```

But this isn't awaiting anything and the UI still locks when I call:

```
var regions = await DataFunctions.GetAllPostCodeRegions("UK");
```

How do I make this operation async and stop UI locking up?

Comment: You need to call ToListAsync() instead of ToList() and add an await in front of that statement.  This requires Entity Framework 6 or higher.

Comment: Thanks.  I also needed to add `using System.Data.Entity` as using the ctrl + period didn't suggest it for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can Try .ToListAsync or:

```
public static Task<List<string>> GetAllPostCodeRegions(string country)
{
    return Task.Run(() => 
       {
          using (var db = new PlaceDBContext())
          {
               return db.PostCodes
                        .Where(pc => pc.Country == country)
                        .OrderBy(pc => pc.Region)
                        .Select(pc => pc.Region).Distinct().ToList();
          }
      });        
}
```

Comment: I said both options, make it by your self is not that hard